# Finding a formula for a pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I have this pattern which is an infinite sequence (I have placed commas so it's easy to see the pattern)...

$1 ,1 2, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4, 1 2 3 4 5 ...$

Is there any formula governing this sequence, ie, If I gave you an index, would you be able to run it through a formula that outputs the digit at that index?

Comment: FYI: http://oeis.org/A007908

Comment: What happens after 123456789? is it 1234567890, 12345678901, and so on? or is it 12345678910, 1234567891011, and so on? or what?

Comment: @GerryMyerson its 123456789,12345678910,1234567891011...

Comment: @mathlove That problem is similar but there's a huge difference: Multi-digit numbers are not counted as one number for my problem, they are counted as separate numbers. Ie, the number $10$ just has $1$ then $0$ as digits in their own indexes

Comment: This may not help to answer the question, but if you put a decimal point in front, $$.123456789101112131415\dots,$$ you get what is known as *Champernowne's number*, about which there is much information on the web.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the answer I posted? Any questions about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4\dots$$ which is what the given sequence is "converging to" is listed at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A033307). A formula for the $n$th term, due to David Cantrell, is given there, but you'll have to look up the Lambert W-function to understand it.

Let "index" $i = ceiling( W(\log(10)/10^{1/9} (n - 1/9))/\log(10) + 1/9 )$ where $W$ denotes the principal branch of the Lambert $W$ function. Then $$a(n) = mod(floor(10^{mod(n + (10^i - 10)/9, i) - i + 1} ceiling((9n + 10^i - 1)/(9i) - 1)), 10)$$

Some of that is a bit confusing, but aside from doing a little bit of TeX formatting I have tried to copy it as it's given at the OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer to your question, but it reminds me of the [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

Under this *mixed-radix* system, the sequence $A_n=(n!-1)$ yields:

- $0$
- $10$
- $210$
- $3210$
- $43210$
- $543210$
- $\dots$

Comment: @DanielR: You're right. I've essentially removed the answer, leaving some related information that might be useful for OP or for anyone else trying to write-down a proper solution. Thanks.